# Beware of our kingdom!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> We all live in a kingdom
>     Sometimes big, sometimes small
>     We bring shivers, happiness or boredom
>     Among other emotions you'll recall
>
> You want to see the last of us first?
>     Doing this, I suggest not to
>     Or for you, our bond will be burst
>     Curiosity's a bad thing, you knew?
>
> Be sure to meet us one by one, it's the only cost
>     Follow our bond or you'll get lost
>     Don't be afraid, our number can vary
>     But you will reach the end, surely.

Who are we, what is the kingdom and what is our bond?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are:

> <s>Books?</s> Chapters

We all live in a kingdom
Sometimes big, sometimes small

> <s>A bookshelf has big books and little books</s> A kingdom is a book. Big chapters, little chapters

We bring shivers, happiness or boredom
Among other emotions you'll recall

> Books bring lots of emotions

You want to see the last of us first?
Doing this, I suggest not to

> <s>In a series</s> You should read a book in order, so don't start by the last chapter!

Or for you, our bond will be burst
Curiosity's a bad thing, you knew?

> If you read a <s>series</s> book out of order, it gets confusing, and the magic of reading doesn't pull you in. The bond refers to the story.

Be sure to meet us one by one, it's the only cost
Follow our bond or you'll get lost

> <s>^Series</s> ^In order

Don't be afraid, our number can vary

> <s>Long series, short series</s> Lots of chapters, not a lot of chapters

But you will reach the end, surely.

> <s>If you have all of the books</s> If you read all the chapters, then of course you'll reach the end.

Title:

> First letters spell out 'book' *(Thanks, @Techidiot!)*